# Making build for EXTJS4-Dont know how to pass params with index.html

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am in the Sencha SDK Tools folder and I am making build for Extjs 4. For the following command
sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3 -v

My index.html is called in the application with certain parameters, so I dont know how to specify the entry point here in this command, if I write it with params it gives lots of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use SDK Tools for Ext 4.x+. Use [Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) instead.

Comment: With Sencha cmd, it was saying it cant recognize the create command....So, I went in the sencha cmd folder and tried creating app.jsb3 in that folder, still it was giving the same error that it cannot recognize the create command

Comment: Sencha Cmd does not generate jsb3 file but it analyzes the source code directly and creates the production build. jsb files are not used anymore.

Comment: Hey Saki, Thank you. But, how should I give my projects path to sencha cmd. For me, as soon as I open my sencha cmd window,it executes some statements and then closes down by itself

Comment: Sencha Cmd is a command-line utility. You can find the manual here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command